# Detect UP and DOWN arrow button clicks on WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scrollbar

I have a very simple ListView which binds to an ObservableCollection of strings. I can use the 'ScrollBar.Scroll' property to detect when someone clicks on the scroll bar and tugs it up or down, but how do you detect when they click the UP or DOWN buttons at the top and bottom of the ScrollBar? Clicking these does not seem to fire the Scroll event.

I'm sure it must be something straight-forward, but I've searched for about an hour without success.

TIA

Comment: What are you attempting to do when the user clicks the buttons? There's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

private void listView_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{

listView.selectedIndex = Convert.Int16(e.VerticalOffset)
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attached event `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged`

*Example*

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="listView_ScrollChanged"
          ... />
```

*Event handler*

```
private void listView_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // You will end up here everytime the `ListView` is scrolled
}
```